# How to connect multiple cassandra intances using single odbc driver ( from SAS ETL)

Tags: cassandra, sas, odbc, etl

We are facing challenges to connect multiple Cassandra instances using a single ODBC driver. We have a SAS ETL server using that we want to connect multiple Cassandra instances, but we are not able to figure out how to do this?

Comment: Can you connect to one instance?  Show what you have tried.  Explain how it does not work.  Do you get error messages?  Connect to the wrong instance?

Comment: @Tom, Yes I am able to connect to one instance successfully, now I am not able to figure out how I can connect two instances at a time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ODBC driver installed, you can connect to different Cassandra clusters as long as you configure the appropriate ODBC URL/DSN connection for each cluster.

If for example, you want to configure the driver to use multiple contact points, you can only do it if you are connecting to a DataStax Enterprise cluster since that is an enterprise-only feature in the Simba Spark ODBC driver which connects to the AlwaysOn SQL Service in DSE. Cheers!